# msodbcsql searches for and loads libssl outside of LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: mysql, linux, openssl, odbc, shared-libraries

I am working on a Linux/C++ application and I want to use the Microsoft ODBC driver (`libmsodbcsql.so`)

At startup, my application crashes because of a conflict with the libssl. After investigation, I realized that:

- my application loads `libssl.so.1.0.0`; this is perfectly normal:

  - because some 3rd parties of my application have always depended on it
  - and overall, `libssl.so.1.0.0` is in my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- my application also loads `libssl.so.1.1`... let's say far less perfectly normal

  - `libssl.so.1.1` isn't at all in my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

I found on part of the explanation on [Microsoft ODBC Programming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/programming-guidelines?view=sql-server-ver16#bkmk-openssl)

> Starting with version 17.4, the driver loads OpenSSL dynamically, which allows it to run on systems that have either version 1.0 or 1.1 without a need for separate driver files. Starting with version 17.9, the driver supports OpenSSL 3.0 in addition to the previous versions. **When multiple versions of OpenSSL are present, the driver will attempt to load the latest one**.

...

> A **potential conflict may occur** if the application that uses the driver (or one of its components) is linked with or dynamically loads a different version of OpenSSL. If several versions of OpenSSL are present on the system and the application uses it, it is highly recommended that one be extra careful in making sure that the version loaded by the application and the driver do not mismatch, as the errors could corrupt memory and thus will not necessarily manifest in obvious or consistent ways.

Using `strace`, I can see that **the driver search all the Linux system, to find the most recent installed libssl, not taking care of what is specified in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`!!!**

I am now searching for a proper way to bypass this mechanism? This could be:

- doing something (I don't know why) so that my program won't see `libssl.so.1.1`
  -...

(**Of course I don't want to alter my system (and any client system) by removing `libssl.so.1.1`**)

Thanks for helping